# Rails - routes - weird errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a rails 4 app.

I just created a scaffold for Universities.

The universities table has three attributes, being :name, :logo, :post_code.

I created three universities as a test. They come up in the console.

The university.rb model has these associations:
The university model has these associations:

```
has_many :faculties
  has_many :students
  has_many :academics#, through: :researchers
  has_many :educators
  has_many :faculties
  has_many :courses, through: :faculties
  has_many :programs#, through: :academics
  has_many :alumnus

  has_one :policy_ip
  has_one :policy_publication
  has_one :policy_commerciality

  has_many :eaip_assets
  has_many :commercial_ip_assets
  has_many :community_activities
  has_many :ip_transfer_successes
  has_many :spin_outs
  has_many :ip_asset_managers#, through: :universities
  has_many :expression_of_interest_options#, through: :ip_asset_manager,  -> { where submitted: true }
  has_many :expression_of_interest_assignments#, through: :ip_asset_manager,  -> { where submitted: true }
  has_many :expression_of_interest_licensings#, through: :ip_asset_manager,  -> { where submitted: true }
  has_many :expression_of_interest_collaborations#, through: :ip_asset_manager,  -> { where submitted: true }
  has_many :expression_of_interest_spin_outs#, through: :ip_asset_manager,  -> { where submitted: true }



  has_many :awards
  has_many :profiles
```

The view university#show has:

```
  <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="profilet"><%= @university.name %></div>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_university_path(@university) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', universities_path %>
```

The first error I get (on each of my 3 records) is:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

When I change the line so that it is on:

```
    <div class="profilet"><%= @university.try(:name) %></div>
```

I get an error on the 'edit' link that says:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"universities", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

When I delete the edit link and try again, I get a blank page with a 'back' link.

I can't understand whats going wrong. My console shows I definitely have 3 records in the university table (each with an id 1, 2 or 3). My routes are resources - (as they are with all of my other models) and this is the first problem I've encountered with the edit link.

I have strong params in my universities controller for each of the three attributes in the table, so I"m stuck for things to try to do to fix this.

Any ideas?

The universities controller has:

```
class UniversitiesController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :set_university, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /universities
  # GET /universities.json
  def index
    @universities = University.all
  end

  # GET /universities/1
  # GET /universities/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /universities/new
  def new
    @university = University.new
  end

  # GET /universities/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /universities
  # POST /universities.json
  def create
    @university = University.new(university_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @university.save
        format.html { redirect_to @university, notice: 'University was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @university }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @university.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /universities/1
  # PATCH/PUT /universities/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @university.update(university_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @university, notice: 'University was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @university.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /universities/1
  # DELETE /universities/1.json
  def destroy
    @university.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to universities_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_university
      @university = University.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def university_params
      params[:university].permit(:name, :logo, :post_code)
    end
end
```

Comment: please include your view fully, where `@university` comes?

Comment: The problem is most probably in your `UniversitiesController#edit`  method.

Comment: The code snippet belongs to which view page? Please post the full code

Comment: It just sounds like you haven't defined the `@university` variable before rendering the view.  Usually you would do this in the corresponding controller action, eg `@university = University.where(:id => params[:id]).first` or something along those lines.

Comment: What is the name of the view page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you didn't have object university in the actions. You have to enable the line below:

```
before_action :set_university, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: Hi, this worked, together with respond_to :html. Strange that those bits aren't generated by the scaffold

Answer (score 0):

The associated instance variable `@university` is `nil` therefore the route helper could not generate a route for it.

Please check your controller's `edit` action and fix the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

You have @university with the id=nil, if you want to use edit url helper you need to provide @university entity with the id. In other words you can edit record that exists in DB, otherwise you should create new.

Answer (score 0):

Wow you have a lot of problems here.

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

This means one of your variables is not initialized. The *cause* of this is where the fun begins.

---

When you define `<%= @university.x %>`, you're calling a *method* on your `@university` variable. If that variable is not populated with any data, or is undefined, Ruby automatically assigns the `NilClass` class to it.

You mention you're seeing this error when referencing the `@university` variable. This means either in your *routes* or *controller*, it's not being populated.

Here's how to fix it:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :universities #-> url.com/universities/:id
#app/controllers/universities_controller.rb
class UniversitiesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_university, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def index
      @universities = University.all
   end

   def edit
   end

   def show
   end
end
```

This should give you the capacity to use the following:

```
#app/views/universities/show.html.erb
<% if @university %>
   <%= @university.name %>
<% end %>
```